# Как обработать строку на поисковые операторы?

Tags: php, sphinx

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обработать строку запроса на операторы поиска.
Операторы: `"`, `!`, `=`, `|`.

Т.е. нужно строку разложить на эти операторы и информация которая в них или вне - экранировать.

```
    private function getMatchWithSeparator($string){
    $separators = ['!', '"', '|', '='];

    if(substr_count($string, '"') % 2 != 0) return Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($string);

    $array = explode(' ', $string);

    if(count($array) == 1 && $array[0][0] === '!') return '';

    $query = [];
    foreach($array as $item){
        if(strlen($item) < 3){
            $query[] = ($item == '"')? $item: Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($item);
        } else {
            $first = (isset($item[0])) ? $item[0] : '';
            $second = (isset($item[1])) ? $item[1] : '';
            $last = substr($item, -1);

            if ($second == '"') {                                                                        /*   !", =" и другие*/
                if (in_array($first, $separators) && $first != '"' && $last == '"') {
                    $str = substr(substr($item, 0, -1), 2);
                    $query[] = $first . $second . Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($str) . $last;
                } elseif ($first == '"' && $last == '"') {                                              /* если слово в ковычках*/
                    $str = substr(substr($item, 0, -1), 1);
                    $query[] = $first . Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($str) . $last;
                } elseif (in_array($first, $separators) && !($last == '"')) {                           /* если слово начивается с спецсимвола */
                    $str = substr($item, 2);
                    $query[] = $first . $second . Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($str);
                } elseif ($last == '"') {                                                               /* если слово заканчивается ковычкой*/
                    $str = substr($item, 0, -1);
                    $query[] = Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($str) . $last;
                } else {
                    $query[] = Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($item);
                }
            } else {
                if ($first == '"' && $last == '"') {                                          /* если слово в ковычках*/
                    $str = substr(substr($item, 0, -1), 1);
                    $query[] = $first . Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($str) . $last;
                } elseif (in_array($first, $separators) && !($last == '"')) {                  /* если слово начивается с спецсимвола */
                    $str = substr($item, 1);
                    $query[] = $first . Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($str);
                } elseif ($last == '"') {                                                     /* если слово заканчивается ковычкой*/
                    $str = substr($item, 0, -1);
                    $query[] = Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($str) . $last;
                } else {
                    $query[] = Yii::$app->sphinx->escapeMatchValue($item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return implode(' ',$query);
}
```

У меня получилось пока примерно такое (без оптимизации кода). Но иногда бывают сбои, например:

Запрос `!"ds /s ! " df fds"sdfd sf " !!'sdfdsf` даст ошибку....

Виды запросов:

```
Привет !Пока               - Искать без слова Пока
"Как дела"                 - Искать эту подстроку
=Привет или ="Привет мир"  - Искать именно эту словоформу
Привет | Пока              - Или
```

И вот как обрабатывать запрос? Как предусмотреть комбинирование этих запросов? Как защитить себя от кривых запросов?

Comment: более конкретно вы задачу можете описать? что значит разложить? из какой строки и что вы хотите получить для дальнейшей работы?

Comment: Ко мне поступает строка запроса, в ней могут быть использованы операторы поиска: ",  !, =, |.  Нужно передать в функцию экранирования данных, которые находятся между этими оператора и которые не являются операторами.